# I need a verb to replace "to know" in this sentence

Tags: meaning, grammar, verbs, synonyms

This paper seeks to know if  those who perpetuate rape are the only ones responsible.

Comment: What have you found in a thesaurus, and why do those terms not work for you? Why do you not want to use *know*? You need a lot more information and explanation to make this question on-topic.

Comment: Perpetuate or perpetrate?

Comment: investigate (+ whether, not if). But the catenation is unwieldy; one level of personification is ample: _This paper investigates whether ..._. What about 'In this paper, we/the authors investigate whether...' The passive / pseudo-passive needn't rule even scientists' lives.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking about **Determine**.

> This paper seeks to determine if...

I also like **Answer** but you would have to change the end of the sentence then.